# Ladders in the first quadrant

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, physics, alternative-proof

Assume we're looking at the first quadrant in the plane with the positive $x$ and $y$ axes as boundaries. Look at a point $ (a,b) $ in the interior and consider ladders passing through this point, that is, line segments with one end on the $x$-axis, the other end on the $y$-axis and passing through $ (a,b) $. The question is this: what is the minimum length of such a ladder?

The answer is $ (a^{2/3} + b^{2/3})^{3/2} $ as can be found out with some easy calculus. But I'm wondering if there is a physical interpretation for such an answer, in particular for the exponent $ 2/3 $ and its reciprocal. The answer is neat, but the ladder which minimizes this does not have symmetrical $x$ and $y$ coordinate endpoints: $ x = a + (ab^2)^{1/3} $ and $ y = b + (a^2b)^{1/3} $, which is another curious case to ask this question.

Comment: Let $L:=(a^{2/3}+b^{2/3})^{3/2}$. Then, we have $L^{2/3}=a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}$. This reminds me of [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid) whose equation is $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = L^{2/3}$. This is the envelope of a line segment of length $L$ with endpoints on the $x$ and $y$ axes. See the animation [here](https://mathimages.swarthmore.edu/index.php/Envelope).

Comment: I wonder if extending the question to $d=3$ would yield any insight.  Is the answer there (for the minimum-area triangle with vertices on the axes and containing $(a,b,c)$) equally nice in terms of $a,b,c$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a physical interpretation, the given problem is equivalent to a rigid bar with fixed lenght constrained to move keeping end points on each of the axes and also costrained to keep the contact with the point $P=(a,b)$.

In this way, indeed, we set a stationary condition for the length of the line segment passing through $P=(a,b)$ which corresponds to its minimum value.

In such situation, for the first constraint, the [instantaneous center of rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_centre_of_rotation) must be located at $C=(x,y)$ and, for the second constraint, the line $CP$ must be orthogonal to the rigid bar.

Indeed, according to the following sketch

[image]

we obtain geometrically the conditions

$$\frac{x-a}{y-b}=\frac{y}{x}=\frac{b}{x-a}$$

which lead to the given [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%28x-a%29%3Dy%28y-b%29%2Cy%28x-a%29%3Dbx).

---

**Remarks**

1. The physical analogy explains also why point $P=(a,b)$ satisfies the [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid) equation as noticed by [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/78967/mathlove) in the comments.
2. Given $x$ and $y$ by this simple geometrical construction we can find $P=(a,b)$ on the line segment such that the given lenght is the minimum among all others line segments passing through $P=(a,b)$.

---

**Animation for the physical analogy**

[image]